# "The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name" in IBM DB2 with pandas.to_sql if_exists='append'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, db2

Please, help with this problem.
sqlalchemy-1.4.31
pandas-1.4.0
Python 3.6.8

```
engine = create_engine(ConfigDbDb2.sqlalchemy_engine_c_string, )
chumks = pd.read_sql_query(get_goods, engine, chunksize=chunksize)

for i, chunk in enumerate(chumks):
    print(i)
    chunk['predicted'] = chunk['name'].progress_apply(my_function)
    chunk.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=dtype_good_test)
```

After first writing i have

(ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0601N  The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name

Comment: Could you provide more context, more details? It seems that your statement is trying to create a table which already exists. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0500-sql0749#sql0601n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, for some reason, sqlalchemy + pandas ignore schema parametr in connection string when appending. So you should define it directly in the to_sql statement of pandas dataframe like

```
chunk.to_sql(table_name, engine, schema = 'MY_SCHEMA', if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=dtype_good_test)
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting more information into an answer.